# SQL - Sum Up Results Of A Multiplication By Group

Tags: sql, database, join, group-by

I have the following tables:

> Orders (OID, Count, ProductID, TableNr)
>
> Table (TableNr, Name, Number)
>
> Products (ProductID, Prize)

Now I want to calculate how much was earned per table. I think to do this I have to Group By Orders.TableNr. But how can I multiply the Products.Prize with the Orders.Count and after that sum up this results within the group?

Comment: Show a sample data. This way it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: Please don't ask us to write your code. Show what you are able to do. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a join and aggregation:

```
select o.tableNr, sum(o.count * p.prize) totalEarned
from orders o
inner join products p on p.productId = o.productId
group by o.tableNr
```

If you want to display table information as well (say, the table name), then you can add another `join`:

```
select t.tableNr, t.name, sum(o.count * p.prize) totalEarned
from table t
inner join orders   o on o.tableNr   = t.tableNr
inner join products p on p.productId = o.productId
group by t.tableNr, t.name
```

Note that `table` is a SQL keyword, hence not a good choice for a table name.